# Three level expandable list view collapse all but selected in second group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a problem when trying to collapse all groups in nested expandable list views.

I have an expandable list view and each child is another expandable list view. What I want to do is when expanding one item of the second list to collapse all other.

m are the expandablelistview childs of the first expandable.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MetrobusStation station = lines.get(groupPosition).getStations()[childPosition];
    final MetrobusStationExpandable m = new MetrobusStationExpandable(activity);
    MetrobusStationAdapter mAdapter = new MetrobusStationAdapter();


    mAdapter.setStation(station);
    mAdapter.setLinea(this.lines.get(groupPosition));
    mAdapter.setExpandable(m);

    m.setGroupIndicator(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down_w));
    activity.setGroupIndicatorToRight(m);

    m.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    m.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Log.i("click at child",String.valueOf(childPosition));
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });

    exps.put(groupPosition, m);

    return m;
}
```

This code is not logging the "click at child", it's not entering when clicking, any ideas?

Comment: Hi pam, is your problem solved, i'm struggling with the same issue now.. can u plz post..

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a HashMap with the items and added an onclick like this:

```
private HashMap<String, MetrobusStationExpandable> exps = new HashMap<String,                MetrobusStationExpandable>();
            MetrobusStation station = lines.get(groupPosition).getStations()[childPosition];
    final MetrobusStationExpandable m = new MetrobusStationExpandable(activity);

    mAdapter.setStation(station);
    mAdapter.setLinea(this.lines.get(groupPosition));
    mAdapter.setExpandable(m);m.setGroupIndicator(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_down_w));
    m.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    m.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            for (String clave: exps.keySet()) {
                try { exps.get(clave).collapseGroup(0); }catch(Exception e) {}
            }
            m.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This one worked for me. Take the import and field instance variable. 

import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;

public class MyDialog extends Dialog implements
        OnGroupClickListener{

  private int lastExpandedGroupPosition = -1;


    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {
        parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);      

        if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
            parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        } else {
           parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
        }

        return false;
    }



       public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {

            if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
            }

            lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

    }
```